# IE-8 Compatible issue with Primefaces?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, internet-explorer-8, primefaces

Hi i am having a problem with IE -8 because when i execute my code in Chrome and mozilla it is good ! but in IE-8 it is not executing properly. saying that dialog.show is not defined

```
<p:calendar value="#{bean.method}" mode="inline">
<p:ajax update="@all" event="dateSelect" listener="#{Bean.method1}" oncomplete="dialog.show()" />
```

```
<p:schedule id="dialog" initialDate="#{Bean.method3}"/>
```

showing Errors .
When i click on the Date Calendar the Date in the Schedule is getting displayed.
but in IE-8 when i click on the date the Calendar and Schedule are vanishing, when i refresh the page i see that my Selected date has been selected and i also found an error saying as above..(Sorry about the Question if anything is Wrong in Explaining neatly :))

Comment: post your <p:dialog content...

Comment: you see the id i have used in the schedule..i think this is not working

Comment: Yes i tried that one but no use.instead before i have given    <p:ajax update="schedule" event="dateSelect" listener="#{Bean.method1}" oncomplete="dialog.show()" /> & <p:schedule id="dialog" initialDate="#{Bean.method3}" widgetVar="schedule" /> ..so for multiple selections i have changed update="@all"

Comment: not sure .. but, try adding widgetVar="myschedule" to p:schedule and change oncomplete="dialog.show()" into oncomplete="myschedule.show()" but anyway , aren't you looking for a way to update the schedule ? use oncomplete="myschedule.update();" instead

Comment: i was able to update the schedule with my previous code only....the attribute oncomplete="myschedule.update()" is not working..i tried...my previous code is toatally good in chrome..but not in IE thts what my problem is..?

Comment: hey daniel just post u r comment as an answer..i think i got the answer of u r "oncomplete="myschedule.update();" i checked again..it worked with my code..just modifying u r given oncomplete..

Comment: ok , posted , so eventually adding widgetVar="myschedule" and using oncomplete="myschedule.update();" did the effect you were looking for?

Comment: actually i have used both update & widgetVar ,but when u said to combine update with widgetVar "IT WORKED REALLY GOOD"  Thanks for that one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `widgetVar="myschedule"` to `<p:schedule` and change

```
oncomplete="dialog.show()"
```

into

```
oncomplete="myschedule.update();"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of issues with IE and primefaces components not working until I had a fix that solved everything in one go. I realised that if i put the below code to be the first line in the head everything worked like a charm.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
        <h:head>

        <f:facet name="first">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
         <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
        </f:facet>
       // other head code goes here

       </h:head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the first line of the file xhtml.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```